# Limit of $\frac{N^{n}(N!)^{n}}{(n-1)!}$ as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

How to prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N^{n}(N!)^{n}}{(n-1)!}=0?$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [ratio test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) we have

$$ \frac{N^{n+1}(N!)^{n+1}}{(n)!}\frac{(n-1)!}{N^{n}(N!)^{n}}=\frac{N\, N!}{n}\to 0$$

Comment: So limit of the ratio is less than 1,thus the given limit exist. How to conclude the limit of the given question is $0$ ?

Comment: When the limit of the ratio is less than one the limit is zero!

Comment: Really?!. Now Only I came to know this. Anyhow thanks much. Is any proof available for this?

Comment: @AvinashN: it is an easy matter to show there there are numbers $a$ and $b<1$ such that for sufficiently large $n$, $0\le t_n<a b^n$.

Comment: That’s a very simple proof related to the definition of limit! I search a link for that.

Comment: Take a look here [proof](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence)

Comment: @gimusi thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if something is not clear! Bye

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N^{n}(N!)^{n}}{(n-1)!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M^{n+1}}{n!}=\frac{M^{M}}{M!}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M\cdot M\cdot M\cdots M}{(M+1)\cdot(M+2)\cdots(M+n)}
\\<\frac{M^{M}}{M!}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac M{M+1}\right)^n.$$

Comment: Sorry for the (maybe stupid) question but what is $M$?

Comment: @gimusi: $N\,N!$.

Comment: And why in the first step we obtain $M^{n+1}$?

Comment: @gimusi: because we have $n!$. (All these details are not so important, what matters is the geometric upper bound.)

Comment: Sorry I’ll take a look by myself later!

Answer (score 0):

Your numerator is $\alpha^n$, where $\alpha=N.N!$. So, we have the limit of $\frac{\alpha^n}{(n-1)!}$, which is $0$; since $\alpha$ is constant.